# can't not reach any page using angular-cli http-server to deploy

Tags: angular, deployment, server, angular-cli

My project if use 'ng serve' to run, can work. But once deploy on server using 'http-server ./dist', can't not visit any page, it will display the error info like below:

```
host:~/morange/project$ http-server ./dist
Starting up http-server, serving ./dist
Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:8083
http://***.**.*.**:8083 (sorry, author comment this ip)
http://**.*.*.*:8083  (sorry, author comment this ip)
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Wed Dec 21 2016 09:56:45 GMT+0800 (SGT)] "GET /login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
[Wed Dec 21 2016 09:56:45 GMT+0800 (SGT)] "GET /login" Error (404): "Not found"
```

chrome will also display error like this:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:58431:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:58409:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:47123:31)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:5802:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:5776:18)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:47126:34)
    at FirstSubscriber._complete (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:63685:25)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:5788:18)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._complete (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:30253:30)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://172.28.2.60:8083/main.bundle.js:5788:18)
```

this is part code of the route

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainBaseComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'basicinfo',
            component: BasicInfoComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'demand-sub-category',
            component: DemandCategoryComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'demand-trend-compare',
            component: DemandCompareComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'newpush',
            component: NewPushComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'pushrecord',
            component: PushRecordComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
        ]
      },

    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

'script' of package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "server-start": "http-server",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g http-server",
    "postinstall": "ng build && mv dist/* ."
  },
```

Comment: waiting your answers on site, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's missing a valid base href !!

Add in your index.html

```
<base href=".">
```

Or while making your prod build with angular-cli,
run the command

```
ng build --prod --base-href .
```

P.S :Dont forget the . (dot)

Comment: hi, Parth, I first change<base href="/"> into <base href=".">, and run 'ng build --prod --base-href .' (with the dot), but I didn't help.

Comment: <head>
  <base href=".">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PSP</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>     the header is like above

Comment: can u plz try the following in your route file
path: '',
component: MainBaseComponent,
redirectTo:'basicinfo'
pathMatch:'full'

Comment: imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainBaseComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'basicinfo',
            component: BasicInfoComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'demand-sub-category',
            component: DemandCategoryComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          }
        ]
      },

    ])
  ],

Comment: @JACK
can u plz try the following in your route file 

path: '', component: MainBaseComponent, redirectTo:'basicinfo' pathMatch:'full'

This will redirect to basicinfo whenever there is '' in your route, u can change basicinfo to whatever that should be redirected by default.

Comment: ([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainBaseComponent,
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch:'full',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'basicinfo',
            component: BasicInfoComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'demand-sub-category',
            component: DemandCategoryComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
        ]
      },

    ])

Comment: I will use stupid way to use github trace to roll back till find the reason

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the reason, this the code in routing before, seems can't go to any page:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainBaseComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'basicinfo',
            component: BasicInfoComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'demand-sub-category',
            component: DemandCategoryComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
         ]
        }
      ])
```

this is the code after I do some change for routing, then use ip and the port, will be leaded to login page.

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
         path: '',
         component: LoginComponent,
      },

      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainBaseComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'basicinfo',
            component: BasicInfoComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'demand-sub-category',
            component: DemandCategoryComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
          },]
    }
  ])
```

I think the path '' should be set in the outer layer. Not clear about the reason, will dig into angular2 routing.

Answer (score -3):

http-server doesn't support html5 mode which I think is why you're getting 404 - https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/80

try https://github.com/scottcorgan/pushstate-server